# PHP OOP calling method in preg_replace function

Tags: php, oop, twitter

I want to make mentions similar to Twitter but for the user profiles i use ID not userNames so i creat a function that get the UserID based on userName and in a procedural code is working but in oop dosent ..

```
$title = ' Hey @Stackoverflow can u help me ?';

$mentions = (preg_replace("/\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,30})/e", 
    "'<a href=\"http://mySite.com/user:'.$this->mentionName('$1').
'\">@$1</a>'",$title));
```

expected url result

http://mySite.com/user:1

not expected result

http://mySite.com/user:Stackoverflow

// This is a loop not a single string

Comment: Just don't use `e` https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_preg_replace_eval_modifier

Comment: You need to use preg_replace_callback

Comment: i try that , result http://mySite.com/user:'.('Stackoverflow').'

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

Look into [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) function, or assign your match to another variable, and use that for your class function.

Comment: OK but the $mentions and $title are in __construct and function mentionName is outSide..

Comment: Then define the callback function as an array ($class, $method)... and if outSide isn't in scope then you need to make it in scope

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `preg_replace` in combination with a function that evaluates the result and modifies it, use `preg_replace_callback`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
function returnUser($matches){
    return $this->mentionName($matches[1]);
}

$mentions = preg_replace_callback("/\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,30})/e", "returnUser",$title));
```

Comment: Try again. Forgot to add `_callback`

Comment: Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'returnUser', to be a valid callback in

Comment: . Btw in function mentionName is a query that pull the data from database

Comment: `return $this->mentionName($matches[1]);` won't work from that function. The `preg_replace_callback` should work, otherwise check the documentation and do some testing.